# How to write test case for a method that only derives variables

Tags: scala, unit-testing, intellij-idea, testcase

I have method in my code which is used to derive only variables.

```scala
def futurenet(config: PipelineConfig): StageContext => Unit = 
  Processor { context =>
    val year = config.year
    val month = config.month
    val folder = year+""+month
 
    val exception = "year=" + year + "month=" + month
  }
```

I tried to call the method in my test and assert. But the code coverage is not enhanced. Please guide on how to write test cases for this piece of code.

Comment: this method looks weird. What is `Processor` ? And how are you writing test case for this ?

Comment: `context` is not used, you are passing some lambda to `Processor.apply` which uses local variables and returns `Unit`. Other than initializing variables and reading from `config`, there is nothing there - there is no value returned nor side effects that you could check for. You cannot test this code because it seems to be completely redundant and replacable with `_ => ()`.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Unless `Processor.apply` is a macro.

Comment: @DmytroMitin it is a possibility, but I would be surprised if OP was able to write a macro but not a test for it.

Comment: @Jansirani So, would you provide us the code of `Processor`?